# Custom manipulator for changing at what characters a std::istream split words

Tags: c++, c++17, stream, localization

## Introduction

By default, input streams (e.g., `std::cin` or a `std::istringstream`) split words at space when using the `>>` operator.  If we want to split at other characters (e.g., `\n`), we need to use `std::getline`:

```
std::vector<std::string> lines;
for (std::string line; std::getline(std::cin, line);) {
    lines.push_back(std::move(line));
}
```

However, many interfaces are designed for use with `>>` only (e.g., `std::istream_iterator` or the typical `operator>>` of a container).  I implemented a **custom manipulator** that allows the user to specify at which characters words should be split, so that the aforementioned loop can be converted into a call to `std::copy`: (hopefully the awkward syntax can get better with C++20 ranges)

```
std::cin >> set_delim("\n"); // magic here

std::vector<std::string> lines;
std::copy(std::make_move_iterator(std::istream_iterator<std::string>{std::cin}),
          std::make_move_iterator(std::istream_iterator<std::string>{}),
          std::back_inserter(lines));
```

`set_delim` can also be used for other purposes — for example, `>> set_delim(",")` helps when parsing comma-separated lists.  More than one delimiter can be supplied — for example, `>> set_delim("0123456789")` causes `01I2know34I'm5not678alone9` to be parsed as `I` `know` `I'm` `not` `alone`.

## Implementation notes

The whitespace behavior of `std::istream` is not easily customizable; what I did is change the underlying `ctype` facet of locale associated with the stream.  Here are some points to consider:

- We are overwriting how `isspace` of the locale works, but other properties are retained.  For example, after `std::cin >> set_delim(',')`, `std::isspace(' ', std::cin.getloc())` is no longer true, but `std::isalpha('A', std::cin.getloc())` is still true.  There are some test cases about this point in the online demonstration.
- The interface of `std::ctype<char>` (lookup tables) is fundamentally different from that of the other specializations of `std::ctype` (virtual functions).  I only implemented the `char` case for simplicity.  The implementation basically builds up a new lookup table by modifying that of the underlying locale (see the previous point).
- `set_delim` is intended to be used as a manipulator only, so it uses `std::string_view` internally to pass the delimiters.  Thing like

  ```
  auto manip = set_delim(std::to_string(42));
  std::cin >> manip;
  ```

  will cause dangling pointers.

## Code

set_delim.hpp

```
#ifndef INC_SET_DELIM_HPP_DbZxaxlZMs
#define INC_SET_DELIM_HPP_DbZxaxlZMs

#include <algorithm>
#include <istream>
#include <locale>
#include <string>
#include <string_view>

namespace detail {
    // generate std::ctype<char> style mask table
    // allocated with new to fit the std::ctype<char> interface
    // the std::ctype<char> constructor should be called with del = true
    const std::ctype_base::mask*
    new_table(std::string_view delim, std::locale underlying_locale)
    {
        static constexpr auto table_size = std::ctype<char>::table_size;
        auto underlying_table = std::use_facet<std::ctype<char>>(underlying_locale).table();

        auto table = new std::ctype_base::mask[table_size];
        // copy underlying table, with the space mask unset
        std::transform(underlying_table, underlying_table + table_size, table,
                       [](std::ctype_base::mask mask) {
                           return mask & ~std::ctype_base::space;
                       });
        // set the space mask for delimiters
        for (auto c : delim) {
            table[static_cast<unsigned char>(c)] |= std::ctype_base::space;
        }
        return table;
    }

    class ctype_space : public std::ctype<char> {
        using Base = std::ctype<char>;
    public:
        ctype_space(std::string_view d, std::locale l)
            : Base{new_table(d, l), true}
        {
        }
    };

    struct set_delim_manip {
        std::string_view delim;
    };

    std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, set_delim_manip manip)
    {
        auto underlying_locale = is.getloc();
        is.imbue(std::locale{
            underlying_locale, new ctype_space{manip.delim, underlying_locale}
        });
        return is;
    }
}

auto set_delim(std::string_view delim)
{
    return detail::set_delim_manip{delim};
}

#endif
```

An [online demonstration](https://wandbox.org/permlink/N9njUZubldi2PGsE) with test cases is available on Wandbox.

## Usage example

```
#include "set_delim.hpp"
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::cin >> set_delim(",");

    std::copy(std::istream_iterator<std::string>{std::cin},
              std::istream_iterator<std::string>{},
              std::ostream_iterator<std::string>{std::cout, "\n"});
}
```

Input:

```
a b, c d ,e f
```

Output:

```
a b
 c d 
e f
```

(The second line has a trailing space.)

[live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/dCz6etueNdLl9GGN)

Comment: I find the set_delim("1234567890") very unintuitive. I would expect the entire sequence to be the delimiter. Instead you could provide an overload accepting two input iterators representing a range in container containing the allowed delimiters as individual container elements.

Comment: That's a clever idea, to use the facet like that.  I'm impressed!

Comment: Love it. Always a fan of using local and facet to simplify the usage of streams. Very good.

Comment: Very good work.

Answer (score 1):

I could have written the code better ...

---

## Removing violation of the one-definition rule

I made a silly mistake — I violated the one-definition rule by failing to mark the following functions `inline`:

- `new_table`
- `operator>>`
- `set_delim`

I was too accustomed to writing templates ...

---

## Preserving the `toupper`, etc. behavior of the original locale

The `ctype_space` facet inherits from `std::ctype<char>` rather than the type of the current facet in the locale because dynamically determining the base type to derive from is not possible.  Unfortunately, this also means that the overridden versions of virtual functions are lost.  Copying the underlying lookup table ensures that the semantics of the `is` function is preserved because they use the table instead of relying on dynamic dispatching; however, the following functions use dynamic dispatching and their custom semantics is lost:

- [`toupper`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/ctype/toupper)
- [`tolower`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/ctype/tolower)
- [`widen`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/ctype/widen)
- [`narrow`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/ctype/narrow) (takes an additional fallback character argument)

The protected virtual `do_` version of each of these functions has two overloads, operating on a single character and a sequence of characters respectively.

Correctly forwarding the behavior of the original facet requires storing the underlying locale:

```
class ctype_space : public std::ctype<char> {
    using Base = std::ctype<char>;
    std::locale underlying_locale;

    const Base& underlying_facet() const
    {
        return std::use_facet<Base>(underlying_locale);
    }
public:
    ctype_space(std::string_view d, std::locale l)
        : Base{new_table(d, l), true}
        , underlying_locale{l}
    {
    }
    char do_toupper(char c) const override
    {
        return underlying_facet().toupper(c);
    }
    const char* do_toupper(char* first, const char* last) const override
    {
        return underlying_facet().toupper(first, last);
    }
    char do_tolower(char c) const override
    {
        return underlying_facet().tolower(c);
    }
    const char* do_tolower(char* first, const char* last) const override
    {
        return underlying_facet().tolower(first, last);
    }
    char do_widen(char c) const override
    {
        return underlying_facet().widen(c);
    }
    const char* do_widen(const char* begin, const char* end, char* dest) const override
    {
        return underlying_facet().widen(begin, end, dest);
    }
    char do_narrow(char c, char fallback) const override
    {
        return underlying_facet().narrow(c, fallback);
    }
    const char* do_narrow(const char* begin, const char* end,
                          char fallback, char* dest) const override
    {
        return underlying_facet().narrow(begin, end, fallback, dest);
    }
};
```

---

## Minimizing usage of `new`

The `new_table` function allocates memory for the lookup table using `new`.  The underlying facet is responsible for deleting the memory because I passed `del = true` to the constructor.  I should have used `std::unique_ptr` to control the memory and `release` the ownership at the end to ensure exception safety.

But now that I think of it, I don't need dynamic allocation at all.  I can simply make the table a member of the `ctype_space` facet, and pass `del = false`.  The table will still live as long as the underlying facet.

---

I'm pretty sure I came up with a fourth issue at some time, but I can't seem to recall it right now ...